# The delete key stops working: a vi annoyance on a mac

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

Suddenly, and for no apparent reason, the delete key on my mac will no longer backspace in vi.  Has anyone else experienced this problem?

The delete key works in OpenOffice, so it is not a HW problem with the key.  I did the :map command in a vi session and got this.

```
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX                                             
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
v  <BS>          "-d
v  <D-x>         "*d
v  <D-c>         "*y
v  <D-v>         "-d"*P
n  <D-v>         "*P
```

If I do a vim -u NONE, the delete key moves one to the left but it does
not erase the character the cursor is sitting on.

Comment: if it is like what you described, I think the key may have problem, check the keyboard with other application.  Otherwise, please report what you have done and tried. E.g. plugins recently installed, settings recently changed, have you tried starting vim without any plugin and customized settings, does backspace work? what do you have in your vimrc file?...

Comment: Does your key do something else than backspace or it just does nothing? Is it posssible than you remaped it inadvertently (you can use `:map` to check all of your mappings)? To debug that you can try to start vim without sourcing your vimrc with `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose set backspace?`

Comment: backspace=    is all I see.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, though my solution was different:

```
:set backspace=2
```

Fixed it for me.  I found the answer [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems).

Answer (score 0):

I experimented.  I typed

```
:stty erase (delete key)
```

I got an error message, but the vi began behaving correctly again.
Completely mysterious.